# How to assign the terminal access to electron js project in macOS on production

Tags: reactjs, node.js, macos, electron, homebrew

I am developing a desktop application using electron js platform but I am facing an issue while generating the build of macOS*(homebrew)*, though I have managed to generate .dmg file but whenever I do the installation process in macOS machine at that time it denied due to 'terminal' permission.

I have tried multiple solutions to resolve it, but no success.

**Platform used:**

- electron js
- react js
- react native
- node js
- execa
- sudo

**Snippet:**

```
execa.command('whoami')?.then((result) => {
      console.log('whoami : ', result?.stdout)
      setList([...list, ...['i am ' + result.stdout]])
      // sudo.exec('', options, () => {
        exec('export NONINTERACTIVE=1', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
          console.log('export ', error, stdout, stderr)
          exec(
          // '/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"',
          `echo ${password} | sudo -S curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh | CI=true HOMEBREW_NO_ANALYTICS=true HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP=true HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=true bash`,
          (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            setList([...list, ...['execute command for brew install using sudo']])
            console.log('eeee', error, stdout, stderr);
            setList([...list, ...[error]])
            exec('brew update', (error) => {
              setList([...list, ...['now going for sox install from brew']])
              console.log('error', error);
              installSoxFunc()
            });
          },
        )
      })
      // })
    })
```

**Facing below error:**

```
eeee Error: Command failed: echo 1234 | sudo -S curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh | CI=true HOMEBREW_NO_ANALYTICS=true HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP=true HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=true bash
Password:***Warning: Running in non-interactive mode because `$CI` is set.
Need sudo access on macOS (e.g. the user macbookpro needs to be an Administrator)!

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:312)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:443)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:310)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:672) ==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password)...
 Password:Warning: Running in non-interactive mode because `$CI` is set.
Need sudo access on macOS (e.g. the user macbookpro needs to be an Administrator)!
```

It should allow us 'terminal' permission and install the application on macOS successfully.